# Circleci workflow development using multiple yml script pipelines

Tags: yaml, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows, circleci-orb

I am having a task of putting both **my own test automation code from GitHub** and **DEV team-developed application bundles *.apk, *.ipa bundles available at the Circleci server in the cloud**, install them on the emulators, which were installed on the same Circleci server(*as I can't attach physical devices to a Cloud Server*) then run the feature file(**mvn clean test**) containing CucumberBDD scenarios, then at the end, the e-mailable reports produced by SureFire plugin to the team.

For this whole orchestration, I need to **build a couple of yaml script pipe lines and connect them together to achieve my task**.

What I am lacking is:

- Serious lack of yml script examples for automation.
- lack of documentation about Circleci server and what we can do with it,
  like installing appium, JDK, Android Studio to have emulators installed
  etc.
- lack of understanding and reference for the Circleci 'orb' objects
- General lack of literature on the internet or Udemy about using multiple
  pipelines

Will any one please comment on this with what ever useful information, you have ??
Appreciate the help!!